# Custom theme function and template suggestion

Tags: theming

I'm trying to create a theme function, with a template:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mycustomtheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_function' => array(
      'template' => 'my-template',
    ),
  );
}
```

The my-template.tpl.php file is in the module directory and it works, I have added this to my page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print theme('custom_function', array()); ?>
```

I've tried to copy that template on my theme, but it doesn't work, Drupal always reads the module template, not the theme.

Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mycustomtheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_function' => array(
      'template' => 'my-template',
      'path' => path_to_theme(),
    ),
  );
}

OR for the my-template.tpl.php file is in the module directory

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mycustomtheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_function' => array(
      'template' => 'my-template',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mycustomtheme'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want the theme to pick up the template you need to put it in the theme folder not a module folder.  I doubt very much that the theme system goes looking elsewhere for template files.

Comment: As I wrote, I've copy the template in my theme folder.

Comment: You can't have it in two places at once.

Comment: Every module works in this way: it add a theme function, the "original" template is inside the module and I can copy this template, without renaming it, in my theme. Or not?